# how to deploy wireshark plugin on other machine?

Tags: deployment

I have developed amf plugin for wireshark on ubuntu.
I want to deploy it on other machine.
What are the steps for deploying it on
1 Linux
2 Windows
?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have managed to build your plugin successfully in Ubuntu, you'll find the .so binary in your "wireshark/plugins//.libs" directory. Install Wireshark from the command line and paste the binary in "/usr/lib/wireshark/libwireshark1/plugins". You'll also find other .so binaries in that location. If your plugin is compatible with the installed Wireshark version, then it should work. However, I'm not sure if it'll be compatible across all Linux platforms. Also, I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, it's quite possible the instructions are different for older versions.

For Windows, you'll have to compile it separately on a Windows machine. After that, you'll find the .dll file in "wireshark/plugins/". Just copy it and paste it in "Wireshark\plugins\\" folder, which can be found wherever you installed Wireshark.

Note: Your plugin should have been compiled with the **same** compiler as the one used to build Wireshark. You can see this information in Wireshark by clicking "Help->About Wireshark".